# Windows ROP exploit works only in debugger

Tags: exploit

I created ROP-based exploit for Easy RM to MP3 converter for Windows XP, it works well in Immunity Debugger and WinDbg but doesn't work if I directly launch application without debugger.

Earlier I faced with similar issue in Linux exploit development when the exploit works in GDB but doesn't work without it, this issue was solved by unsetting environment variables.

How can this problem can be solved for Windows XP?

Comment: Configure your debugger to be a post-mortem debugger and run the exploit without a debugger attached. It will attach when the process crashes and you can debug your payload.